# Strict inclusion of eigenvalues relating to spectral mapping theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-radius

I've been working on the spectral mapping theorem and I've come across a hurdle while trying to solve a problem. Let P(x) be a non-constant polynomial, T be a bounded linear operator and denote $\sigma_p(T)$ to be the eigenvalues of a linear operator $T$.

I was able to prove that $P(\sigma_p(T)) \subset \sigma_p(P(T))$. The converse is a direct consequence if the space is finite-dimensional. However, I am unable to prove the converse for infinte-dimensional spaces.

Requesting for hints or a counterexample

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume we have $P(T)w=\lambda w$ with $||w||=1$. We may no define also $Q(z)=P(z)-\lambda z$, since $Q$ is some polynomial over $\mathbb C$ we can find some representation $Q(z)=\prod_{i=1}^n(z-\lambda_i)$ and therefore we have
$$0=Q(T)w=\prod_{i=1}^n(T-\lambda_i)w.$$
Now $v_n:=(T-\lambda_n)w=0$ or we go iteratively $v_{n-1}:=(T-\lambda_{n-1})v_n=0$ and so on. So, there is some $k$ such that $(T-\lambda_{k})v_{n-k+1}=0$. In other words, $\lambda_k$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ with some eigenvector $u$. With that we already know that $P(\lambda_k)\in\sigma_p(P(T))$. It follows now from $0=Q(T)u=P(T)u-\lambda u$
$$P(\lambda_k)u=P(T)u=\lambda u.$$
So it holds, $\lambda=P(\lambda_k)\in P(\sigma_p(T))$, hence $\sigma_p(P(T))\subset P(\sigma_p(T))$.

Comment: I believe this may not work. Cause I have been digging a bit and I have come across the result that $\sigma_c(P(T)) \subset P(\sigma_c(T))$ and $\sigma_r(P(T)) \subset P(\sigma_r(T))$. And the spectral mapping theorem states that $\sigma(P(T)) = P(\sigma(T)$. The above set inequalities may be strict. so we can not have the point spectrum to be equal in all conditions. Here r and c denote the residual and continuous spectrum respectively.